# What's a good workflow for using TextMate project files?

Tags: textmate

I've used Textmate for years but have never actually used project files. I've tried a few times but they always interrupt my workflow compared to `mate .`. Here are the problems I can remember:

1. Where to keep the file? Probably not checked into the source code… so then, it can't live inside the project directory. `~/tm_projects`? Seems kind of clumsy.
2. The project doesn't automatically detect new files, right? So if I create a new file at the command line I have to manually add it to the project. Or is this only the case for new directories? I can't remember. All I know is it royally frustrates me every time I try to use projects.

So, what's a good workflow for using project files, and what are some benefits I'll get from using them?

Comment: Just for newer users coming along: this thread is regarding TextMate 1.X, not TextMate 2. The concept of a project in TM2 is folder based (^⌥⌘-D to open file viewer, then see the "use as project folder" item in the drop down menu in this pane), not an arbitrary collection of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use project files all the time. For example, you might have environmental variables you set on a per project basis (locations of things), or files you want ignored in the file listing.

What I do is create a folder, in each project, called _PERSONAL, and put my TextMate project file in there. This approach works very well for me.

As for files not getting automatically added, there are kind of two ways to create a project:

1. File → New Project, then drag folders into the project.
2. Open a directory, then go to File → Save Project

Approach #2 will automatically add new folders/files as they are added to the directory tree. Approach #1 is more static.

Comment: Thanks, helpful! What else do you put in _PERSONAL? I assume you ignore this in your scm. Why not just ignore the textmate project file?

Comment: Usually just my TextMate project, it's true. So it does feel sort of pointless to have a whole folder there, but I see it as being there for future expansion

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't use project files. I just drop a folder onto TextMate (or open a previous folder from File>Open Recent). According to the [manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files), "The advantage of saving a project is to maintain state (e.g. which files were open) and to be able to quickly re-open a particular set of files. If you leave a (saved) project open when you quit TextMate, it will automatically re-open that project the next time you launch TextMate."